# chrome: How to do Printing Command

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

There are two ways to giving printing command for a document in Chrome Web Browser i.e.

a) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

b) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd>

To do printing for the first method following code is used:

```
<input type="button" value="Print this document" onclick="window.print()" />
```

But how to do printing by method b?

Comment: What is the difference between Ctrl + P and Ctrl + Shift + P?

Comment: @Ivar A lot of difference. Ctrl + P in Chrome bases show print preview window. Ctrl + Shift + P shows Windows/OS base Print/Preview Windows. Kindly runt the command as feel the difference yourself

Comment: Ah alright. Wanted to avoid that I accidentally started printing. Oddly enough this shortcut is not mentioned on [the help page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en). Would be useful to know exactly what it is called.

Comment: @Ivar I don't know what it is called or mentioned on chrome web page or not. But the important thing is Feature is there and how to do things in requested question